# Spring Cloud Bootstrap Config prepending "bootstrapProperties-" to all of my BootstrapProperties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

My team and I updated a spring boot application in order to work with oauth2, but with the updated we jumped from Spring Boot 1.5.2 to Spring Boot 2.5.8. The oauth2 is now implemented although the new version of the app cannot found any client encryption keys from the config server. Checking the logs of the last version I have:

```
INFO  Nov 17 16:30:51 [main] org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration: LOCAL_HOST:, APP_ID:, OPERATION_NAME:, TRANSACTION_ID:, CALL_PATH:, REMOTE_HOST:, USER: - Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource [name='fulfillments-event-validation-job'], MapPropertySource [name='config-internal']]]
```

After this log there are several **com.esrx.inf.config.client.CustomEnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer*** logs where it loads the values of config server and decrypts them

But in the new version I have this logs:

```
INFO  Nov 18 02:25:53 [main] org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration: LOCAL_HOST:, APP_ID:, OPERATION_NAME:, TRANSACTION_ID:, CALL_PATH:, REMOTE_HOST:, USER: - Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configClient'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-fulfillments-event-validation-job'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-config-internal'}]
```

After this log there are not even one log for **com.esrx.inf.config.client.CustomEnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer***

The old app can load and decrypt the config server values, the new version doesn't even load the values of config server.

| old version | new version |
| --- | --- |
| spring-boot-starter-test 1.5.2 | 2.5.8 |
| it does not have this one | spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap 3.0.5 |
| spring-cloud-starter-config 1.3.0 | 3.0.6 |
| configService | bootstrapProperties-configClient |
| fulfillments-event-validation-job | bootstrapProperties-fulfillments-event-validation-job |
| config-internal | bootstrapProperties-config-internal |

So I'm thinking the error is with the values of the new version, for some reason is prepending en every value the string "bootstrapProperties-". You know any related to this issue?

I changed the configuration of my pom and application.properties several times.
At the end I stayed with spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap in order for the app to run.

Comment: It's just the name of the property source. Does it cause a problem?

Comment: please show minimal sample code